# React Router-DOM - Switch only shows root path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The issue is that path `"/"` works, path `"/meow"` doesn't. It doesn't show any errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
    function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/meow">Meow</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <h1>Home</h1>          
          </Route>
        <Route path="/meow">
          <h1>Meow</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

react router checks if the pattern is matched sequentially, therefore, `/any` matches `/` and react displays the first link matching the pattern, here `/`. To avoid that you could reorder links but that's more complicated than else. React implemented a `exact` property to match exactly the pattern :

```
function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/meow">Meow</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <h1>Home</h1>          
          </Route>
        <Route path="/meow" exact>
          <h1>Meow</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes `exactly` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add exact attribute to the `<Route path="/">`

Example

```
<Route path="/" exact>
  <h1>Home</h1>          
<Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

With React Router, inside a `<Switch>` you always want the more specific route on top, because it stops searching after the first match. You can also add `exact` as a prop.

```js
 function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <Link to="/meow">Meow</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/meow">
          <h1>Meow</h1>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <h1>Home</h1>          
          </Route>
        
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

or

```js
 function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <Link to="/meow">Meow</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <h1>Home</h1>          
          </Route>
        <Route path="/meow" exact>
          <h1>Meow</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: note it's not the best way to do it as you have to reorder your routes every time you add a new one. `exact` is the easiest way to make it work

Comment: True! I wouldn't say it's not the best way because it keeps a nice overview of the route tree. At least in my opinion.

Comment: @user14337693 make sure you mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

You must use exact in Route component.because without exact prop The first match is selected and All paths that start with / become home components

```js
    function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/meow">Meow</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <h1>Home</h1>          
          </Route>
        <Route exact path="/meow">
          <h1>Meow</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add router tag in the enveloping component